# How can I transform echo replies from requests for if statement counter in Bash?

Tags: shell-script

I'm trying to using the ping command in an if statement where from the get go a certain number of requests would be sent e.g; `ping -c 6 hostname` and consider the statement successful `if [ $result -gt 4]` of those packets, *in a **lossy link** for instance*, make it back.

I more or less have figured it out but only sending individual packets per command (`ping -c 1 hostname`), which take much longer and don't reflect the connection state all that well. I found a real interesting where with piping `grep` and `wc` I could potentially count the words as integers, except it didn't went that far, it only focused on single packet testing too, unfortunately.

Writing to a file is another way but I don't want to write even if it's overwritten in the next loop (this all will be in loop) and never really grows.

What I'm trying to do is to test if a file server is available; if it is mount it, if it's not don't *and* unmount the shares that lost their connection ASAP so the system doesn't hang or maybe bring up a tunnel. I managed to do it in AppleScript and with `automountd`/`autofs` but I'd to use a Bash script bc [1.] it's the only scripting language I *sort of* understand and [2.] to test fast and continuously in little packet batches that would allow for some leeway when switching back into a network to connect quickly or avoiding hanging the system when switching out of it.

Even if there'a a better way, I'd still like to learn how to transform `grep`ped lines from a single command to quantify them and use them in if statements.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You want to test whether at least 4 out of 6 packets are received, i.e. whether there is strictly less than 50% packet loss (3 packets received out of 6 would mean 50% loss).

```bsh
if ping -c 6 "$server" | awk -F, '/packet loss/ { exit !((0+$3) < 50) }'
then
    printf 'Server "%s" is alive and returning more than 50%% of packets\n' "$server"
else
    printf 'Server "%s" is in bad shape\n' "$server"
fi
```

The `awk` command looks at the line containing the text `packet loss` in the output from `ping`.  In the third comma-delimited field on that line, there is a number, the packet loss percentage, that we get by interpreting the field in an arithmetic context (by adding zero to it).  We exit from the `awk` code with a status reflecting whether the packet loss was strictly less than 50% (zero = yes, non-zero = no).

Comment: Thanks. I think I'll have to dive into the `awk` man pages. I've avoided it so far bc it seems intimidating but looking at both answers I think it's about time. At least I got two different examples to get me started. Thanks for answering!

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `awk` to count the number of successful replies.

```
if ping -c6 "$server" | awk '/bytes from/ { k++ } END { exit !(k>=4) }'
then
    echo OK
else
    echo Dubious
fi
```

Each line matching `bytes from` increments the counter, `k`. The exit status is success (zero) only if `k >= 4`

Comment: Thanks! It's not that the network is bad, it's just a DMZ where the server is unreachable, regardless; I took the chance to try to learn this. I was reviewing some random arithmetic examples in Bash that look pretty similar, I guess this will be it. Thanks!